# Password or Email is wrong message at login is insecure

Tags: bug, security

today i have seen a problem with the Stackoverflow login mechanism.

At my opinion a service which tells the user: your email is wrong and if the email is correct it says the password is wrong is definitely not secure.

Because if some wants to get access to some account he types an email address which could be correct and changed it a little bit until he gets the message the password is incorrect.
At this moment he knows the email address is registered.
After that he tries some passwords which can be maybe possible if he knows the person or he use a dictionary attack. 
I think this problem should be fixed.

[image: Password is incorrect pic]

Comment: Knowing the Stack Exchange team, I'm sure this is the result of very careful thinking. There *may* have been a related discussion on the topic somewhere (on security.stackexchange.com?) but I can't find it

Comment: One does not specify a username when logging in.  The email *is* the username.  So you cannot determine if a particular account is using a particular email, but rather whether a particular email happens to be registered with *any* account.  That's a noticeably different thing to know, and not something that I see any potential ways of abusing, really.

Comment: @Pekka i have also nothing related found if the same report exists already than im sorry

Comment: @Sevy maybe some one knows the some emails of a person and so he can tests which one is correct and tries some passwords or not?

Comment: @Zelldon That's like trying to keep the list of usernames secret for an authentication system.  It's just not secret information that you don't want people knowing.  You don't prevent people from knowing someone's username, you prevent them from knowing the password that goes with it.  In this case that means not letting people submit tens or hundreds of thousands of password attempts, a very easy thing to do.

Comment: @Servy ok maybe your are right im sorry. i thought it is much better to say that one of them is wrong not explicit which one

Comment: Related discussion on Information Security: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/62661

Answer (score 1):

This is only a problem if accounts and IPs aren't blocked from trying after a while.  Online dictionary attacks are trivial to prevent.